# XmlResourceParser returns diffrent count of attributes on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-vectordrawable, xmlresourceparser

I'm playing with the new vector xml drawables on older platforms like Kitkat or Gingerbread. I have an image like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="300dp"
        android:viewportWidth="300"
        android:viewportHeight="300">
    <group>
        <path
            android:fillColor="@color/primary"
            android:pathData="@string/svg_path_background" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff"
            android:pathData="@string/svg_path1" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="@color/primary"
            android:pathData="@string/svg_path2" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

The exact values don't matter, that works fine on Lollipop. However I try now to read this xml file (from the drawable directory). This works fine, except that in every tag one attribute is missing. I have no clue why this happens:

```
public static void load(Resources res, int drawable) {
    XmlResourceParser vector = res.getXml(drawable);
    int type = -1;
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    while(type != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        try {
            type = vector.getEventType();
            switch(type) {
            case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                xml.append("<");
                xml.append(vector.getName());
                for(int i = 0; i < vector.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
                    xml.append(" ");
                    xml.append(vector.getAttributeName(i));
                    xml.append("=\"");
                    xml.append(vector.getAttributeValue(i));
                    xml.append("\"");
                }
                xml.append(">\n");
                break;
            case XmlResourceParser.END_TAG:
                xml.append("</");
                xml.append(vector.getName());
                xml.append(">\n");
                break;
            }
            vector.next();
        } catch(XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d("XML-Test", xml.toString());
    vector.close();
}
```

The output of this code above is this here on Kitkat and Gingerbread:

```
<vector height="300.0dip" width="300.0dip" viewportHeight="300.0">
<group>
<path pathData="@2131624234">
</path>
<path pathData="@2131624248">
</path>
<path pathData="@2131624249">
</path>
</group>
</vector>
```

And the correct output on Lollipop:

```
<vector height="300.0dip" width="300.0dip" viewportWidth="300.0" viewportHeight="300.0">
<group>
<path fillColor="@2131296323" pathData="@2131624234">
</path>
<path fillColor="#ffffffff" pathData="@2131624248">
</path>
<path fillColor="@2131296323" pathData="@2131624249">
</path>
</group>
</vector>
```

Is it possible that this is a bug of the build system? I don't get how the differnt outputs are possible. I'm using AS 1.0.2 with buildToolsVersion 21.1.2

Comment: What is targetSdkVersion?

Comment: 21 else I cound not run that code on Lollipop ;-)

Comment: Hmm,  strange,  btw did you see telly/MrVector?

Comment: Ask uncle google for telly/MrVector

Comment: A cool I did not find that library yet, that does almost that what I want to achieve. However I would like to know why I cannot read that attributes.

Comment: Respect,  like a great explorer... where is your drawable.xml placed?

Comment: *"I try now to read this xml file (from the drawable directory)"* so it is `res/drawable/example.xml`. :-)

Comment: I missed that,  what if you place it in raw or xml folder?

Comment: i got it, try this: aapt d xmltree your.apk res/drawable/example.xml

Comment: Here is [the output](http://pastie.org/private/wovwof1x17nt8l6ucvoha), please note this is a differnt drawable, however the tags have equal arguments.

Comment: so viewportWidth is missing after building... seems you have to tell the build tool to include API21 attributes

Comment: also see this: https://github.com/telly/MrVector#basic-inflate, seems that telly has the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of the Android build tools check also [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=100910).